# Appending a file in /system/ location in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to append a file that already exists in /system/ location through my app but I am unable to give the specific path in my code. I have granted supersu permission and permissions for writing in internal storage. Do I need to mount /system before appending?

Comment: Did you mean "append *to* a file", or something else?

Comment: you want internal storage file path right ?

Comment: Yes @AnilMeenugu /system/etc/

Comment: I think you need to remount RW - /system is mounted RO most of the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Context.getFilesDir()` method to get the path to the internal storage

Edit

when using this line `FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = openFileOutput(name, MODE_PRIVATE);` the internal storage path is obtained by the default implementation of the `openFileOutput()` method. A new file is created at that location with the specified name. Now when you want to get the path of the same file, you can use the `getFilesDir()` to get the **absolute path** to the directory where the file was created. You can do something like this :-

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir() + "/" + name);
```

you can manually create your `FileOutputStream` in append mode with:

```
FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)
FileOutputStream(String path, boolean append)
```

Or alternatively and arguably preferably, by using the native android method:

```
openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
```

Which opens a file named 'FILENAME' located in the default storage location for your app. It is usually best to let the OS decide where to store your files. Details on storage options here. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: File file = new File(getFilesDir() + "/" + name); Basically, this line is getting the location of file? and the " +name " is the file name in /system/? Can you explain me please?@AnilMenenugu . I m new to android coding.